# How to get the Java File AbsolutePath() with only just file name?

Tags: java

So im testing out the getAbsolutePath() of java.io.File and when i provided it with the full path like this it work fine

```
    File filePath = new File
    ("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg");
    System.out.println(filePath.getAbsolutePath());
```

it print out the correct path of the file

```
    /home/ubuntu/Downloads/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg
```

but when i change the filePath like this

```
    File filePath = new File ("batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg");
```

it print out

```
    /home/ubuntu/workspace/testservlet/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg
```

so what i want to know is is there anyway i can get the correct filepath from just the name of the file like "batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg" and why it print out this path when i provide only filename

```
    /home/ubuntu/workspace/testservlet/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg
```

Comment: You can't, if you don't provide the right path, the directory will be the current working directory.

Comment: okay thank you i think that all i want to know

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
File filePath = new File("/home/ubuntu/Downloads/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg");  
System.out.println(filePath.getAbsolutePath().substring(filePath.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
```

Comment: thank for your help but what i want is get the 

/home/ubuntu/Downloads/batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg

from only the filename "batman-face-funny-hd-background.jpg" but seem like it cant